# Checking whether android wifi/Mobile data is currently downloading or Bluetooth is currently communicating with its pairs

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi

in my application I need to shut down Wifi,Mobile Data and Bluetooth after a certain period of time programmatically. But, before shutting down those network services I want to check whether my device is downloading/uploading any file using Wifi/Mobile data . In case of Bluetooth I want to check whether bluetooth is currently sending/receiving any file from any of its pairs. In these two cases I won't shut down my services.

From http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html , i found following code which states whether wifi/mobile data is connected or not :

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

So, if my device is pulling data from facebook/mail server the connectivity returns true.

Is there a way to identify whether the connectivity is due to downloading/uploading files using wifi/mobile data or bluetooth file sharing?

Comment: Buddy I have similar requirement ? Did you find any solution on it ?

Comment: Nope , if you find any plz leave a comment :(